# How can I find the cause of the error: "failed to find configured root that contains"

Tags: android, delphi, android-fileprovider

I have an error and I can't find the cause of it. Error while generating Uri.

I looked through several topics on this topic, which were discussed here. However, the error could not be corrected. I think there is a typo somewhere. How can I find where I am wrong?

```
var
files: Tfile;
lIntent: JIntent;
lJRecipient: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
lURI: Jnet_Uri;
LAuthority: JString;
lJFile: JFile;
lFileName: string;
lFilePath: string;
lFilePathFileName: string;
Surf : TBitmapSurface;
begin
 lFileName := Concat('Foto','Code' ,'.jpg') ;
 lFilePath := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetPublicPath;
 lFilePathFileName := System.IOUtils.Tpath.Combine(lFilePath, lFileName) ;
 Surf:=TBitMapSurface.Create;
 SaveParams.Quality:=100;
 try
  Surf.Assign(imResult.Bitmap);
  TbitMapCodecManager.SaveToFile(lFilePathFileName, Surf, @SaveParams);
finally
  Surf.Free;
end;

  lIntent:= TJIntent.Create;
  lIntent.setType(StringToJString('message/rfc822'));
  lIntent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND);
  lIntent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  lIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL, lJRecipient);
  lIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString('Text'));
  lIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT, StringToJString('.....'));
  LAuthority := StringToJString(JStringToString(
  TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationContext.getPackageName)+'.fileprovider');
  lJFile:= TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(lFileName));
  lUri := TJFileProvider.JavaClass.getUriForFile(
    TAndroidHelper.Context,  LAuthority, lJFile);
```

I have included in the manifest file

```
<provider
                android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="com.embarcadero.ScanDecoder.fileprovider"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true"
                android:exported="false">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
            </provider>
```

Created a file  \res\xml\filepaths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="MyFoto" path="."/>
</paths>
```

I tried changing the path in the file to the following. I am still getting this error.

```
path="."
path="./"
path="files/"
path=".files/"
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Using GetPublicPath likely requires an entry in `filepaths.xml` of: `<external-path name="external_public_files" path="." />`

Comment: @Dave Nottage Didn't help unfortunately.
What should I include in the name="..."?
Maybe the problem is buried here?

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider, specifically the section "Specifying Available Files". In this case, I doubt the name matters, so if that entry does not work, I'm not sure what your issue is. On Android GetPublicPath definitely refers to getExternalFilesDir, which corresponds to `external-path` in the provider paths.

Comment: I'm also assuming that you're using a version of Delphi before 10.4. The manifest and provider paths xml are catered for automatically by checking the Secure File Sharing option in the Entitlement List of Project Options in 10.4 and later.

Comment: @Dave Nottage Yes. I am using version 10.4

Comment: 10.4 is not *before* 10.4. Is there some reason you're not using the built-in feature?

Comment: @Dave Nottage  If I use the "Secure File Sharing" option and use TJFileProvider.JavaClass.getUriForFile nothing changes. If I use "Secure File Sharing" and  lFilePathFileName := System.IOUtils.Tpath.Combine(lFilePath, lFileName) ;
         lURI := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.fromFile(
               TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(lFilePathFileName))); i am getting this error. "opened outside the application via the getUri ClipData element"
How to save the file correctly? Maybe in a different directory?

Comment: Please use `TAndroidHelper.JFileToJURI` with your `lJFile` reference. You won't need `LAuthority` as this work is done for you by `JFileToJURI`. If you update your code, please update it in the question

Comment: @Dave Nottage Huge gratitude! That's how it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dave Nottage suggested the correct way to work with FileProvider.
The xml manifest and provider paths are generated automatically when you enable the "Secure File Sharing" option in the list of rights in the project options.
Now it works.
I provide a working solution.

```
procedure TestSendEmail();
{$IF DEFINED(ANDROID)}
 var
  lIntent: JIntent;
  lJRecipient: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
  lURI: Jnet_Uri;
  lFileName: string;
  lFilePath: string;
  lFilePathFileName: string;

  Delim :Char;
//  Surf : TBitmapSurface;
{$ENDIF}


begin
 lFileName := Concat('MyFile' ,'.jpg') ;
 lFilePath := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetPublicPath ;
 lFilePathFileName := System.IOUtils.Tpath.Combine(lFilePath, lFileName) ;
 Surf:=TBitMapSurface.Create;
 SaveParams.Quality:=100;
 try
   Surf.Assign(imResult.Bitmap);
 // Save file
   TbitMapCodecManager.SaveToFile(lFilePathFileName, Surf, @SaveParams);
 finally
   Surf.Free;
 end;
{$IF DEFINED(ANDROID)}
  lJRecipient:= TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1);
  lJRecipient.Items[0]:= StringToJString('xxxxxxx@yyyy.com');

  lIntent:= TJIntent.Create;

  lIntent.setType(StringToJString('message/rfc822'));
  lIntent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND);
  lIntent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  lIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL, lJRecipient);
  lIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString('Subj'));
  lIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT, StringToJString('Text'));

  lUri:= TAndroidHelper.JFileToJURI(
      TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(lFilePathFileName)));

  lIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM,TJParcelable.Wrap(lUri)) ;

  try
    TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(lIntent);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage( E.Message);
    end;
  end;
{$ENDIF}
end;
```